# Zend Module Loading

Tags: zend-framework

in our online server, mod_rewrite extension is not configured, Can we override this through .htaccess "RewriteEngine On" ?

The default module is loading properly but the other module are not working only "404 Page Not Found" error is showing.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "is not configured" means "turned off" then the answer is no, you can not. In order to turn it on you have to say so explicitly in httpd.conf (or what have you).

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache22/mod_rewrite.so
```